# Spring MVC Controller Exception Test

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test, springmockito

I have the following code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "admin/category/edit/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editForm(Model model,@PathVariable Long id) throws NotFoundException{
    Category category=categoryService.findOne(id);
    if(category==null){
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    model.addAttribute("category", category);
    return "edit";
}
```

I'm trying to unit test when NotFoundException is thrown, so i write code like this

```
@Test(expected = NotFoundException.class)
public void editFormNotFoundTest() throws Exception{

    Mockito.when(categoryService.findOne(1L)).thenReturn(null);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/admin/category/edit/{id}",1L));
}
```

But failed.
Any suggestions how to test the exception?

Or should i throw the exception inside CategoryService so i can do something like this

```
Mockito.when(categoryService.findOne(1L)).thenThrow(new NotFoundException("Message"));
```

Answer (score 16):

Finally I solved it. Since I'm using stand alone setup for spring mvc controller test so I need to create **HandlerExceptionResolver** in every controller unit test that needs to perform exception checking.

```
mockMvc= MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(adminCategoryController).setSingleView(view)
            .setValidator(validator()).setViewResolvers(viewResolver())
            .setHandlerExceptionResolvers(getSimpleMappingExceptionResolver()).build();
```

Then the code to test

```
@Test
public void editFormNotFoundTest() throws Exception{

    Mockito.when(categoryService.findOne(1L)).thenReturn(null);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/admin/category/edit/{id}",1L))
            .andExpect(view().name("404s"))
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/404s.jsp"));
}
```

Comment: what is the getSimpleMappingExceptionResolver() implementation?

Comment: I found out this : http://www.mytechnotes.biz/2012/11/spring-mvc-error-handling.html .  Looks like <strong>org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver</strong> is already a Spring class

Comment: @josete the domain name has changed  
https://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2012/11/spring-mvc-error-handling.html