# mockMvc - Test Error Message

Tags: spring-mvc, mockmvc

Does anybody have any tips, or does anybody know how I can test the "error message" returned by the HTTP response object?

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext ctx;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(ctx).build();
}
```

Response:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 200
       Error message = null
             Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
        Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: does [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Response_codes) helps you.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `.andExpect(model().hasNoErrors())` will do the trick

Comment: Any way I can do something like 
    <code>assertEquals("expected error message", "actual error message")</code>
 instead of 
    <code>.andExpect(model().hasNoErrors())</code>

Comment: see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7321

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the method [status.reason()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/StatusResultMatchers.html#reason-org.hamcrest.Matcher-).

For example:

```
     @Test
     public void loginWithBadCredentials() {
        this.mockMvc.perform(
                post("/rest/login")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content("{\"username\": \"baduser\", \"password\": \"invalidPassword\"}")
                )
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized())
                .andExpect(status().reason(containsString("Bad credentials")))
                .andExpect(unauthenticated());
    }


    MockHttpServletResponse:
                  Status = 401
           Error message = Authentication Failed: Bad credentials
            Content type = null
                    Body = 
           Forwarded URL = null
          Redirected URL = null
                 Cookies = []
```

Answer (score 9):

Even simpler:

```
String error =  mockMvc...
    .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized())
    .andReturn().getResolvedException().getMessage();

assertTrue(StringUtils.contains(error, "Bad credentials"));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution I found using JsonPath and MockMvc

```
this.mvc.perform(post(BASE_URL).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(responseJson)).andDo(print())
.andExpect(status().is5xxServerError())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.message", is("There is an error while executing this test request ")));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `jsonPath` seems to work only when "Body" is not empty, which is true for the above case.

Answer (score 3):

it works for me:

```
.andExpect( status().reason( "invalid.duplicate" ) )
```

Comment: By itself? Without e.g. `.andExpect(status().isUnauthorized())`, as proposed in other answers?

Comment: it's just a code snippet, please work with other .andExpect( ... )