# How to document @ControllerAdvice handled exception using Spring REST Docs

Tags: java, spring, testing, documentation, spring-restdocs

I have `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class, which is handling `BadRequestException extends RuntimeException` exception.

Now suppose that I have endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/createAccount")
public ResponseEntity<CreateAccountResponse> createAccount(@RequestBody @Valid CreateAccountRequest createAccountRequest) {...}
```

In case of unwanted scenario, endpoint throws `BadRequestException` (with HTTP Status 400) which constructs error JSON object as following:

```
{ 
  "errorCode": 123,
  "errorMessage: "Failure reason"
}
```

Is there any way to document case like this using Spring REST Docs ?

This is example of my approach:

```
@Test
public void createAccountFailExample() {

       RestDocumentationResultHandler docs = document("create-acc-fail-example",
       responseFields(
                        fieldWithPath("errorCode").type("Integer").description("Error code"),
                        fieldWithPath("errorMessage").type("String").description("Error message")
                )
        );

        org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() -> this.mockMvc.perform(RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.post("/createAccount")
                        .contextPath("/account")
                        .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(new CreateAccountRequest("nameTest", "surnameTest"))))
                        .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                        .andDo(docs)).hasCause(new BadRequestException(ServiceError.SOME_FAIL_REASON));
}
```

In this case test passes, but no documentation (.adoc) files are created.

When I try something like this:

```
ResultActions resultActions = this.mockMvc.perform(RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.post("/createAccount")
                .contextPath("/account")
                .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(new CreateAccountRequest("testName", "testSurname"))))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andDo(docs);
```

test fails because `NestedServletException` was thrown caused by `BadRequestException`, and again there is no documentation created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33311231/5250885). When exception handler is defined for `MockMvc`, my second approach works as expected.